# Shell scripting to make directories using command line argument

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, sh

a) Take command line argument as:

```
./myscript.sh <path> dir1 dir2 dir5 dir2/dir5 dir5/dir7
```

and create directories in

```
<path>/dir1 <path>/dir2 <path>/dir5 <path>/dir2/dir5 <path>/dir5/dir7
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "$@"; do
    mkdir -p -- "$i"
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p -- "$@"
```

Comment: i wasn't sure if it took multiple arguments

Comment: It appears that the first argument to the script should be the directory to create the dirs in

Comment: @that other guy Not really, all arguments are relative to the current directory unless they are absolute paths

Comment: I was talking about OP's example. There, the first argument is the path to create dirs under.